# Error 404 when SockJS client gets http://localhost/sockjs-endpoint/info?t=xx

Tags: spring, sockjs

I encounter an error when attempting to connect a SockJS client in react to my spring server.
It appears that the SockJS client doesn't find the necessary infos -->
[Network and console display of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIs6f.png)

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/project");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/project/**").permitAll()
            .anyMessage().permitAll();
    }*/

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/sockjs-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**SockJS Client**

```
const socketjs2 = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:8080/sockjs-endpoint');
export const stomp2 = Stomp.over(socketjs2);

stomp2.connect({}, function (frame) {
    console.log("STOMP connected :");
    console.log(frame);
    stomp2.subscribe('/project/staff', function (requests){
        logger(JSON.parse(requests), LOGGING_INFORMATIONS);
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("sendind to stomp.")
        stomp2.send('/app');
    });
});
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```